# error al conectar a mongodb

Tags: mongodb, macos

Tengo un problema cuando quiero acceder a la consola de `mongo`, levanto el servicio con `brew` y cuando intento ingresar al `shell` de `mongo` me aparece este error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.8
connecting to: test
2016-08-17T08:47:10.650-0300 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
2016-08-17T08:47:10.650-0300 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6
```

Si veo la lista de servicios me aparece que esta corriendo, pero cuando veo los puertos que se están ocupando, nada esta en el **27017**.

No creo que sea un error de instalación porque antes funcionaba.

alguien tiene alguna idea?

Comment: prueba con `brew services start mongodb`

Comment: Prueba con esto: `brew services restart mongodb`

Comment: Nitroceluloso iniciando el daemon con >mongod como comenta @eledgaar sigue mostrando el mensaje???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comentas que "antes funcionaba", entonces trata esta solución:

dentro de el folder `\db` elimina el archivo `mongod.lock`

```
\data\db\mongod.lock
```

posteriormente ejecuta

```
>mongod --repair
```

Comment: lo intente y sigue igual :(

Answer (score 3):

Yo me fuí a los servicios de Windows 10, busqué el servicio llamado "MongoDB Server (MongoDB)", vi que estaba detenido. Lo inicié, y luego me fui al cmd y ejecuté "mongo" para iniciarlo. Y con eso ya se pudo conectar.

NOTA: Al parecer el servicio detuvo en algún momento del día, ya que el hace un par de días podía conectarme sin problemas.

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que antes de ejecutar `mongo` necesitas crear el directorio para los datos y ejecutar Mongo Daemon:

```
mkdir -p /data/db
sudo mongod
```

Comment: Hola amigo eldgaar, supongo que ya tenia creado el directorio /db ya que menciona antes funcionaba.

Answer (score -1):

una solución para win 10 que me funcionó :
abrir 2 consolas con cmd, luego en una de ellas se coloca `

> mongod

` y en la otra solo se coloca

> mongo

de esa forma se restaura y luego se puede abrir normal con una consola

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Pero Quien pregunto, no pregunta sobre windows. Por lo tanto esta respuesta no tiene nada que ver :(

Answer (score -1):

Yo logré solucionarlo en el siguiente orden. (al final parece ser problemas de bloqueo que hace el router)

```
netsh 
winsock 
reset
```

reiniciar pc

```
mongod
mongo
```

Ojo, también me preocupe de firewall antes de encontrar la solución